# Solver: An unexpected internal error occurred, or available memory was exhausted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the solver from Excel in VBA but I'm having trouble. I keep getting the following error: "Solver: An unexpected internal error occurred, or available memory was exhausted."

Now, I guess solver isn't out of memory as I can solve the same problem when using the solver dialog.

Here's my code:

```
Sub CoolSolverButton()

SolverReset

SolverOK setCell:=Range("$CK$203"), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range("$BH$203:$BQ$222"), Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"

SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BH$203:$BQ$222"), relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BH$223:$BQ$223"), relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("$BH$225:$BQ$225")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BH$227:$BH$245"), relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("$BI$227:$BI$245")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BJ$227:$BJ$245"), relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("$BK$227:$BK$245")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BL$227:$BL$245"), relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("$BM$227:$BM$245")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BN$227:$BN$245"), relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("$BO$227:$BO$245")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BP$227:$BP$245"), relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("$BQ$227:$BQ$245")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BR$203:$BR$222"), relation:=2, FormulaText:=Range("$BT$203:$BT$222")
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$BU$203:$BU$222"), relation:=2, FormulaText:=Range("$BW$203:$BW$222")

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: try without Engine (should it not be 1?) and EngineDesc and post what happens. Also, are those ranges you used correct?

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answering, Simplex LP is the second engine, GRG Non Linear is the first I think.

I found the error, constraints had to be given on a cell per cell basis, now it works...

Comment: We got the same issue when reading the `FormulaText` from a Range(), especially when it had a decimal value. So we had to change it to `FormulaText:="""" & Range() & """"`. If your VBA has a `,` as decimal separator, you may need to add `FormulaText:=Replace("""" & Range() & """", ",", ".")`